# Transmitting data using LabVIEW to a cRIO via TCP or UDP

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, udp, labview

Should I used TCP or UDP as a protocol to send variable packets over a Lan network from my laptop (Using LabVIEW program) to a cRIO (using java).

More specifically, the LabVIEW part is straightforward. But I am new to setting up sockets and receiving data in java.

Comment: I think your question title is wrong, reading your question it is about java and not LabVIEW. And how do you run java on your cRIO?

Comment: Using netbeans we upload java code from Ethernet to the cRIO, it then fails to connect to the dashboard(Labview project)

Answer (score 2):

TCP.

UDP is a "raw" packet protocol, meaning that each sendto() corresponds to a single datagram on the network, with no flow control or error recovery.  If you need to send more than a few hundred bytes, need to be sure the data gets through, need the data to arrive in order, or will be sending data at a rate anywhere near that of the network, then UDP alone will not provide what you need.

There are several reliable protocols built on top of UDP (disclaimer: my company makes one of them).  But unless you have a specific need to avoid TCP (like a need for high performance or low latency), you are better off letting TCP take care of all transport the basics for you.

Comment: I have a need on the latter, information should be sent as close to real time as possible.

Comment: Here's an example where UDP might be appropriate: a small number of bytes being sent at intervals of 100 milliseconds, and it is acceptable if some messages are occasionally lost.  If you need every packet to arrive, you are back to TCP.  It will still be real-time, most of the time, but it will get behind when it needs to do error recovery to ensure every message is delivered.

Answer (score 0):

If you are communicating from your user interface on your desktop/laptop VI to your cRIO and it is not critical, then I would suggest using UDP. There is less overhead when calling UDP because there is no "handshaking" like TCP has. [Here is a great article](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/65BD9AB0126A8886862575660051B07A) with other tips I point people to that are doing programming on cRIO.